# Java x64 и x86 в чем разница?

Tags: java

Откомпилировал одно и тоже приложение примерно по 1000 раз на 86 и 64 разрядной windows 7 результат такой:

Среднее время компиляции на 32: ~28 сек
Среднее время компиляции на 64: ~88 сек

При этом на 32 системе данное приложение запускается в 2-2,5 раза дольше чем на 64-й.

Помогите разобраться в чем все таки разница. И правильно ли будет работать приложение откомпилированное в 32 битной ОС на 64 разрядных машинах.

Comment: Если программа "большая" и имеет "далекие вызовы", то в принципе 32 разрядной машины (2^32 адресов памяти, чуть больше чем 4GB) может не хватать для адресации в ОЗУ и поэтому используется подкачка с жесткого диска, поэтому задержка при загрузке. Работать должно одинаково, по крайней мере, "с точностью" до реализации jvm )

Comment: А железо одинаковое под обеими системами?

Comment: >А железо одинаковое под обеими системами? Да одно и тоже железо

Comment: Сам код не зависит от "битности" системы (В отличии от C#). Вопрос только в реализации самой jvm. Например в 32х битной винде размер кучи не превышает 1,4 - 1,6 гб. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os)

Comment: Просветите, зачем собирать одно и тоже приложение 1000 раз подряд? Стресс тест железа? :) И главное какой результат вы ожидали от полученных цифр? Это время зависит от железа, софта установленного и запущенного паралельно, вашей активности в это время, и ещё масса факторов..

Comment: >Просветите, зачем собирать одно и тоже приложение 1000 раз подряд? >> Просто работаю над одним проектом около года, и привел примерную цифру в 1000 раз.